# frameworks to test scala and Play applications

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is there a framework or library recommended to test Scala programs (regular program, Play framework applications or both)?

Comment: See - https://github.com/lauris/awesome-scala#testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scalacheck](https://www.scalacheck.org/) might be something you want to take a look at, it allows you to do property testing and to write your own property generators for your case classes.
You can try it out and have some explanations [here](https://www.scala-exercises.org/scalacheck/).

Moreover, Play gives you [leads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTest) to test your application.

Answer (score 0):

Already there are many default scata test libraries present in Scala .You can try ScalaTest.

You can refer below url:

http://www.scalatest.org/

Thanks